# Trigger Jenkins job only if there is a code change in certain folders

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a Jenkins job hooked up to Github repo and this job is triggered externally (I do not have permission to configure the parent job). 
Now I want to run the job only if there is a code change in certain dirs and ignore running this job if there is only changes in certain dir like `doc, .. etc`

I found that under **Source Code Management -> Addition Behaviour** section, there is a option called **'Polling ignores commits in certain paths' (Jenkins Git plugin)** and configured the following,

```
Included Regions:
    [project]/src/.*
    [project]/test/.*
    [project]/scripts/.*


Excluded Regions:
    [project]/doc/.*
```

But using this, if there is a change only in the `doc` folder also, the build is been triggered and run by the job. How to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

I do not have the [project] reference in my regions.  I use the the relative path from the workspace.

Excluded Regions:

doc/.*

So I have a Typescript code build that uses this: `Emulator/src/.*\.ts`

Maybe you need the extra extensions for your build?

Comment: I tried without giving [projectName]. Even then the build is been triggered

Comment: I will have to watch my build closer today then to see if it is truly not running on these commits.  We have a busy tree so maybe the plugin now has an issue, or we are both misconfigured.

Comment: I validated against my builds, but I use the Include Regions.  I do have my pathing without the preceding current directory indicator `./`. I updated my answer with the difference.

Comment: Thank you Steve. This works only if the job is self triggered based on polling. But this will not work, if this job is triggered by parent job. So I have written  a bash snippet as part of `Build step` to exit if the only the specific path files have been modified :-)

Comment: @ashwin That does make sense as the section is part of the GIT Polling, and not the build selection.  As you launch it from another build, it is not doing GIT Polling, so I am not surprised it does not work as you expected. Glad to see you did get a work around though.